# Persian language support in PHP/MySQL web application

Tags: php, mysql, persian

I'm building a PHP/MySQL web application and I need to have persian language support besides english, french and german.  Can you guys give me some advice regarding this topic? What encoding should I use in order to match all three languages?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at a [Persian Website](http://www.bornaray.com/per_main.asp?fn=en_main&rfn=per_main) should give you some clues. utf-8 seems to be fine (and certainly will be for German/French), but you'll need to set the text direction to rtl (right-to-left) for Persian.

Comment: And I can set the text direction using css. Thanks.

Comment: you can set `dir=auto` to browser the the direction automaticaly